# LOGSTASH filter | Multiple patterns for same file

Tags: filter, logstash, logstash-grok

In my logstash configuration i need to use multiple patterns.My application generate logs in 3 patterns . i tried to use array for multiple pattern but its not working.

```
filter{
    grok{
        match=>{
            "message"=>[
            "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] COMMTRACE user=\[%{GREEDYDATA:userId}\]\, sessionId\=\[%{GREEDYDATA:sessionId}\]\, ip\=\[%{HOSTNAME:ip}\]\, event\=\[%{GREEDYDATA:event}\]",
            "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\] COMMTRACE user\=\[%{GREEDYDATA:user}\], sessionId\=\[%{GREEDYDATA:sessionId}\], ip\=\[%{IP:ip}\]\, type\=\[%{GREEDYDATA:type}\]\, msg\=\[%{GREEDYDATA:msg}\]"
                        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: You didn't escape the comma inside the second pattern (after GREEDYDATA:user), maybe this is the error?

Comment: And the comma after GREEDYDATA:sessionId too

Comment: Thanks @AndreaRomagnoli . its working now

Comment: If this solved the problem, please mark my answer as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't escape the comma inside the second pattern after GREEDYDATA:user, and the comma after GREEDYDATA:sessionId too.